# using CONCATENATE to generate Item Number

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am trying to use a calculated column to grab info from my columns and add the ID number on the end and pad it.  I can get most of this to work, as I build it up but the ID number at the end does not show.  Can anyone have a look and help with this?
Thank you

```
=CONCATENATE(("123456-"&[Group]&"-"&[Area (IA)]&"-"&[Area (S)])&"-"&,REPT("0",6-LEN([ID])),[ID])
```

looking at trying to get "123456-Mec-100-200-000001"

Project number (hard coded for each project)-Group (Choice column)-Area IA (Choice column)-Area (S) (Choice column)-000001 (max 6 digits including the ID number)

Working with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ID column in a formula. If you want to use it, you will need to develop an event receiver or Designer Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated Formulas are processed **before** a new Item is written to the database where it gets an ID.

That is why **ID is empty for New items** but has the correct ID when an Item is changed/updated. (or you change a Calculated Formula, which effectivly updates all items)

If you need ID in a Formula you have to trigger that update for newly created items, simplest is to create a Workflow triggered on New Item which writes the ID value to a extra column MyID.
The Workflow runs after the item is written to the database so picks up the correct ID value.

If you do not want an extra column you can also use a Workflow to overwrite any other field with the existing value, this will trigger an Item update as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SharePoint Designer list workflow to copy the item's `ID` to another column (for example, create an `IDCopy` column) when an item is created or modified. Then use this `IDCopy` column in your calculated column.

Here's a quick workup of a SharePoint Designer workflow:

[image: Workflow]